# A lot action (including "Reformat Code") are disabled in rider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rider

Somehow (only in Rider 2022.3.1, not in Intellij Idea Ultimate) some actions are disabled. This includes the CTRL-Alt-L action "Reformat Code". This action also is disabled when accessed over Main text menu toolbar.

[image]

Other actions are enabled but do not have an effect, like the "Extend Selection" action.

**Any idea what is wrong?**

The project is a Unity 3D (Game engine) project with C# code. No .editorconfig is present. Support for .editorconfig is disabled.

Same project does work fine when opened on another computer with the same Rider version.

Comment: As its not highlighting any of the unity words id say it and unity are not aware of each other

Comment: I would go with the bottom error you get there saying `Unable to connect to MSBuild process to load project 'Assembly-CSharp'` .. maybe some Windows updates running etc? Try to restart and reopen the script .. be sure in your Unity project you have rider package installed and only open the script by double clicking it from within Unity ..